# Htaccess rewriterule /a to /a/b

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to prepare rewrite rule from directory `/a/` to subfolder `/a/b/`, but I receive information that my rewrite rule is circular, so I receive as `output URL` as `localhost/a/b/a/b/a/a/b` in order to request localhost/a/. I would like to receive:

```
localhost/a and rewrite to localhost/a/b
```

I try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/a/b
RewriteRule ^/a(.*)$ /a/b/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `/a/.htaccess` have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /a/

RewriteRule ^((?!b/).*)$ b/$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```

If you want to skip actual files/directories from this redirect then use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!b/).*)$ b/$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```